# Problem display

Tags: custom-field, customization

Hy I have this code:

```
    <?php 
    $id_film_array = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),"info_film", true);
    $id_film = $id_film_array[0];
    $titlu_film = get_the_title($id_film);
?>
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $id_film) );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>


<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($id_film); ?>"><?php echo $titlu_film; ?></a>


<?php 
   endwhile;
   // Reset Post Data
   wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I recive an error if i do not have anithing select. How can i fix this.

For example i do not want to select nothing for some post, in the page i do not want to retrive nothing.

I use Custom Field, Relationship

Comment: I want to display : No movie data..., if i don't select

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the `while` loop with a conditional:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $id_film) );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() )
{
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
        $the_query->the_post();
        // regular output
     endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
}
else
{
    echo 'No movie data';
}
```

Comment: can you give more detail please :)

Comment: where do i put that code?

Comment: @CopilFlavius I have extended the example. Another suggestion: Find a good PHP tutorial, and take the time to learn it. Once you are able to split a problem into the smallest logical parts that the language can express you will be much faster. :)